# perform inequality comparisons to alphanumeric data in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Need help with linq query. I have a column which contains alphanumeric data in it and I want to extract numbers and perform mathematical comparisons. For example >,< etc.

So the data would be like: JS20, MRR12, DEEN2 etc.

I tried converting it to Int but it fails

```
    var TheData = (from p in db.data.Where(l => Convert.ToInt16(l.TextAndNumber) <= 10)
                  group p by p.Names into g
                  select g.Key).ToList();

    return Json(new { data = TheData });
```

Comment: First, apply a regex to filter just the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(from row in db.data
 let digits = new String(row.TextAndNumber.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())
 let number = Int64.Parse(digits)
 where number < 10
 select row.Names
).Distinct();
```

Comment: I get an error: Unsupported overload used for query operator where

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the numbers from the string before applying your conversion.

```
List<string> data = new List<string> { "JS20", "MRR112", "DEEN2" };
var TheData = data.Where(d => Convert.ToInt32(new string(d.Where(char.IsNumber).ToArray())) <= 10);
```

This returns DEEN2.

Comment: Is there anyway I can add do comparisons on alphanumeric column and output a different column instead?